# Why are some words being compressed and spaces between words are being removed when converting html to pdf via dompdf in php

Tags: php, dompdf

Why are some words being compressed and spaces between words are being removed when converting html to pdf via dompdf in php?

If you can see in the attached image, the spaces between "it by", " stand for", "financial standing" and "less (optimum)" are all removed.

[image]

Comment: I have not used dompdf for a long time, but if I remember correctly,  this can be fixed by replacing spaces (and tab characters) with `&nbsp;` before you create the pdf.

Comment: Are they by chance end of line (`\r\n or \n`) in the original text?

Comment: @Michel no, they are not. They are just he normal space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by putting the paragraph contents inside a wordwrap function in php. Example: wordwrap('content string',100)